# What is the purpose of a line of code that says: '_ = viewController.view'?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift-optionals

What is the purpose of the following line of code? It doesn't seem to do anything. If it were in Playground or in a print statement it would at least show something.

```
_ = masterVC.view
```

It's in Apple's sample code at [Sharing CloudKit Data with Other iCloud Users](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/shared_records/sharing_cloudkit_data_with_other_icloud_users).

Here's the complete significant code that contains that line of code:

```
if let masterVC = masterNC?.viewControllers.first as? ZoneViewController {
      _ = masterVC.view
      start ? masterVC.spinner.startAnimating() : masterVC.spinner.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: It's to force a code a `loadView()`, that will be code through `loadViewIfNeeded()`, this will make the `masterVC.spinner` which I assume is an IBOutlet, or created by code in `viewDidLoad()` to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the doc of [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view) from `UIViewController`:

> If you access this property when its value is `nil`, the view controller automatically calls the `loadView()` method and returns the resulting view.

Seeing the project code: `masterVC.spinner`, is a `lazy var` that in `viewDidLoad()` will be added as a subview of its `UITableView`.

Why do this then?

Because when you do:

```
let someVC = SomeViewController()
```

Its `IBOutlet` and its `view` hasn't been loaded yet. You can reproduce it with getting having a `IBOutlet` on that VC, or some subview that will be added to the `view` in `viewDidLoad()`. Try to access the property, it will be `nil` for the `IBOutlet` (and usually crash with if it's declared forced unwrapped), and `subview.superview` will be nil for the other one.

That's also why when you use `UIStoryboardSegue`, in `prepare(for:sender:)`, when you do:

```
if let nextVC = segue.destination as? SomeViewController() {
    nextVC.labelIBOulet.text = "someTextToPass" //It will crash for the same reason
}
```

There, it's rather common to pass the model (here a simple `String`) instead of setting the value of the `UILabel`.

I personally prefer calling `loadViewIfNeeded()` instead, in my opinion it's less strange that invoking the `view` and ignore the returned value.